# Vector Constructor and Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

How can a 3 element vector constructer be multiplied by a Mat in OpenCV?
I tried the following but it throws an error:

```
cv::multiply(src, cv::Vec<_Tp, 3>(2.0, 1.0, 1.0), src);
```

It gives the following error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (src2.type() == CV_64F && (src2.rows == 4 || src2.rows == 1)) in arithm_op, file /Users/abhishek/Documents/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp, line 1275
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Comment: What's the definition of `src`?

Comment: cv::Mat_<cv::Vec<_Tp, 3> >& src

Comment: You want a channel-by-channel multiplication? Just scaling BGR by B*2, G*1, R*1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
cv::multiply(src, cv::Scalar(2.0, 1.0, 1.0), src);
```